# Duda con punteros en C++

Tags: c++

Pasa que tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numero = 20;
    int *dirMemory_number;
    dirMemory_number = &numero;

    // Para imprimir el valor y la dirección de memoria de una variable normal.

    cout<<"Numero: "<<numero<<endl;
    cout<<"Dirección: "<<&numero<<endl;

    // Para imprimir el valor y la dirección de memoria de un puntero.

    cout<<"Numero: "<<*dirMemory_number<<endl;
    cout<<"Dirección: "<<&dirMemory_number<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

El cual me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Numero: 20
Dirección: 0x7ffcd7ea466c
Numero: 20
Dirección: 0x7ffcd7ea4660
```

Los punteros, según tengo entendido, almacenan la dirección de memoria de otra variable. Ahora, si vemos mi código, podrán ver que son dos direcciones de memoria diferentes.

¿Es un error de mi código, o porque es que las direcciones no son iguales?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una pequeña recomendación:  La declaración de punteros en C++ difiere de C: 
`T* ptr; // C++`
`T *ptr; // C`

Aunque ambos son correctos, C++ enfatiza el tipo, C enfatiza la expresión.  Puedes ver este artículo por Bjarne Stroustup, el inventor de C++, respecto a esto:
https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace

Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

**Código 1:**

```c
cout<<"Numero: "<<numero<<endl;
```

Imprime el contenido que tenga la variable `numero`.

**Código 2:**

```c
cout<<"Dirección: "<<&numero<<endl;
```

Imprime la dirección de memoria donde esté alojada la variable `numero`.

**Código 3:**

```c
cout<<"Numero: "<<*dirMemory_number<<endl;
```

Esto imprime el valor al que apunte el puntero (en este caso apunta hacia la variable `numero`).

**Código 4:**

```c
cout<<"Dirección: "<<&dirMemory_number<<endl;
```

Imprime la **dirección de memoria donde esté alojado el puntero**.

> > Ahora, si vemos mi código, podrán ver que son dos direcciones de memoria diferentes.

Claro. Son direcciones diferentes porque en el primero estás imprimiendo la dirección de memoria de la variable `numero` y en el segundo imprimes la dirección del puntero `dirMemory_number`.

Si ejecutamos este código:

```c
cout << "Dre: " << dirMemory_number <<endl;
```

Nos dará la dirección de memoria de la variable `numero`. **¿Por qué?** Porque es lo que tiene guardado el puntero.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes notar que lo que estás trasladando es el valor, no la dirección de memoria de un puntero. Podemos tomar en cuenta como si estuvieras apuntando a los datos de un puntero. En muchas ocasiones podemos utilizar un puntero a puntero. De esta forma apuntarías a la dirección de memoria y no solo a los datos. Esto se utiliza con **puntero